# I saw a short on YouTube about a small girl who was on the street and she realized that she is the main villainess of that story

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I saw a short on YouTube about a small girl who was on the street and she realized that she is the main villainess of that story. Then a blonde little girl approaches her with a villainess attitude and tries to bully her. The first girl recognizes the blonde girl as an extra villainess character of the same story. So she gives a smirk and shows the blonde that she can be wicked too ...the last part though I'm not sure about it. Does anyone please recognize the manhwa?

Comment: Was the YouTube video about the manhwa?

Comment: "and shows the blonde that she can be wicked too"... by doing what?

Comment: Did you watch it with your Youtube account/application? If you did, there might be a chance the video might appear in your history of viewed videos, unless you disabled it like I did.